# Ecore modeling to generate a HashMap dto that holds a HashMap

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, modeling

How to create DTO for `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>` using Eclipse Modeling EMF?

I'm trying the steps described here: http://tweakeclipse.blogspot.com/2009/02/create-maps-in-emf-other-way.html but it allowed me to create a list for `<String, Map<String, String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Instance Class Name property of the newly created `EClass` to `java.util.Map$Entry`?